# Operating on multiple matrices in a for loop using R

Tags: r

I have 1000 matrices named `A1, A2, A3,...A1000.`

In a for loop I would like to simply take the colMeans() of each matrix:

```
for (i in 1:1000){
means[i,]<-colMeans(A1)
}
```

I would like to do this for each matrix Ax. Is there a way to put Ai instead of A1 in the for loop?

Comment: how did you get those 1000 matrices in to R?

Comment: I had a simulation with 1000 runs and I saved the results from every run. Now I would like to take their mean. I understand that it would be easier to save into the same matrix, is there something equivalent to a 1X1000 format like in Matlab?

Comment: There are arrays. Maybe you want to `abind` your matrices? (You'd need the `abind` package.) Otherwise, you could assign to a single array (instead of 1000 matrices) from the start...

Comment: how do you assign matrices to an array?

Comment: What Arun was trying to point you towards, was that you made a mistake in saving each matrix in a separate data structure. Either when you create them, or when you load them from disk, you need to place them all in a list.

Comment: Oh, I meant assign to the array instead of a matrix. Arrays are like matrices, but have more dimensions. E.g., you could assign to `A[run,variable,observation]` instead of `Arun[variable,observation]` (where run is the number of the run you are doing). If you want to put your matrices into an array, I recommend looking into `abind`. Alternately, as joran said, you could put them in a list, but I think an array is cleaner for simulations like this.

Comment: @Frank, hadn't seen my name used that way before :)

Answer (score 3):

So, one way is:

```
for (i in 1:1000){
 means[i,]<-colMeans(get(paste('A', i, sep = '')))
}
```

but I think that misses the point of some of the comments, i.e., you probably had to do something like this:

```
csvs = lapply(list.files('.', pattern = 'A*.csv'), function(fname) {
   read.csv(fname)
})
```

Then the answer to your question is:

```
means = lapply(csvs, colMeans)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand, but maybe you have assigned each matrix to a different variable name? That is not the best structure, but you can recover from it:

```
# Simulate the awful data structure.
matrix.names<-paste0('A',1:1000)
for (name in matrix.names) assign(name,matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3))

# Pull it into an appropriate list
list.of.matrices<-lapply(matrix.names,get)

# Calculate the column means
column.mean.by.matrix<-sapply(list.of.matrices,colMeans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You initial question asks for a 'for loop' solution. However, there is an easy way to get the desired
result if we use an 'apply' function.

Perhaps putting the matrices into a list, and then applying a function would prove worthwhile.

```
### Create matrices
A1 <- matrix(1:4,   nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
A2 <- matrix(5:9,   nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
A3 <- matrix(11:14, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

### Create a vector of names
names <- paste0('A', 1:3)

### Create a list of matrices, and assign names
list <- lapply(names, get)
names(list) <- names

### Apply the function 'colMeans' to every matrix in our list
sapply(list, colMeans)
```

I hope this was useful!

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote already, using a list is perhaps your best option. First you'll need to place your 1000 matrices in a list, most easily accomplished using a for-loop (see several posts above). Your next step is more important: using another for-loop to calculate the summary statistics (`colMeans`).

To apply a for-loop through an R object, in general you can do one of the two options:

1. Loop over by indices: for example:

   for(i in 1:10){head(mat[i])} #simplistic example
2. Loop "directly"

   for(i in mat){print(i)} #simplistic example

**In the case of looping through R lists, the FIRST option will be much easier to set up. Here is the idea adapted to your example:**

```
column_means <- rep(NA,1000) #empty vector to store column means

for (i in 1:length(list_of_matrices)){
mat <- list_of_matrices[[i]] #temporarily store individual matrices
##be sure also to use double brackets!
column_means <- c(column_means, colMeans(mat))
```